# Cambiemos el formato del elemento <code> cuando el mismo es parte de un vínculo de tipo anchor <a>

Tags: discusión, bug, característica-nueva, formato, enlaces

Propongo que se realice el cambio para que al incrustar código dentro de un vínculo en una publicación, el texto del mismo se vea de color azul y no como se ve actualmente de color negro. Esto es porque visualmente no se aprecia que es un vínculo o enlace a otro sitio de la misma página o de página externa.

Actualmente se ve así (pantallazo):

> [image: Formato actual]

Como se aprecia, el código que enlaza a otro sitio apenas se diferencia del código que no está enlazado, mediante una delgada linea azul debajo del mismo (*text-decoration*).

Cómo sugiero que debe verse (pantallazo):

> [image: Sugerencia de cómo debe verse]

Entiendo que se han realizado cambios en el diseño del sitio, por lo tanto no sé si esto es un [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) o puede ser considerado una [caracteristica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracteristica-nueva), solo espero que esta sugerencia sea tomada en cuenta.

> Esto es un [`ejemplo`](https://gbianchi-loves-java.com) de código enlazado.

> Esto es un `ejemplo` de código no enlazado.

Comment: No, hice la prueba creando un link que apunta a una página cualquiera que no he visitado y se ven todos iguales.

Comment: Por si sirve de ayuda, yo que no he entrado en ningún enlace veo esto: https://imgur.com/a/LzuN2tw (Chrome)

Comment: @ordago, los primeros ejemplos son imágenes, el último es un link real de un código metido en un link. No se ven la letras en el color del link, sólo la linea del decorador. Por eso puse un ejemplo al final.

Comment: Al parecer ya hay una sugerencia para arreglarlo en Meta en Inglés: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting/353534#353534)

Comment: Me encanta el link al que dirige ejemplo xDDDDD

Comment: @DanteS. Me diste una idea. XD